# Move builds into a project Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am researching various ways to add builds to my project in artifactory. Ideally, I'd like to set up a policy to look for violations in the builds and leverage the JIRA integration to manage the findings. If anyone has figured this out I would appreciate any help. I am looking at this [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildUpload).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the scope of project by providing query param to you API call. For example, upload build: PUT /api/build?project=‘your_project‘.
Then the build will be uploaded to the build-info repo of specific project.